# PHP : how function return value can't be read

Tags: php, jquery, authentication

I want to make login system with modal bootstrap and PHP and jQuery ,I have this modal shown after login button clicked :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Login Page</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name='username' class="form-control" id="username">
            
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name='password' class="form-control" id="password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <input name='remember' type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="remember">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Remember me</label>
            </div>
            <button type="button" name='login' id='login' class="btn btn-primary mr-auto">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so I have this function of login which depend on User class :

```
function login($username ,$password)
{
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->connect();
    $user = new User($db);    
    $user->username=$username;    
    if($user->check_user()){    
        $user->get_profile();    
        if( md5($password)==$user->password){    
            return 'logined successfully';
        } else {
            return 'password is wrong';
        }
    } else {
        return 'username is wrong';
    }
}
```

and the login.php page code is :

```
<?php
include_once('../includes/functions.php');
    //login
if(isset($_POST['login'])){    
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $remember = $_POST['remember'];    
    $message=login($username ,$password); /// the error is here   
    if($message=='logined successfully' && $remember =='on'){
        $domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost:3308') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;
        setcookie("username",$username,time()+31556926, '/', $domain, false );
    } elseif($message=='logined successfully' && $remember !='on') {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $username;            
    }
}
echo $message;
// end of login
?>
```

and the JavaScript is :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login').click(function(){
        var username =$('#username').val();
        var password =$('#password').val();
        if(document.getElementById("remember").checked==true){
            var remember ='on';
        } else {
            var remember ='off';
        }           
        if(username!='' && password!=''){
            console.log(remember);
            $.ajax({
                url:'login.php',
                method : 'POST',
                data :{username:username,password:password,remember:remember},
                success:function(data){
                    if(data =='logined successfully'){
                        console.log(data);
                        $('#loginModal').hide();
                        location.reload();                          
                    } else {
                        console.log(data);
                        $('#loginModal').hide();
                        alert(data);                                
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert('Both username and password required!');
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

when I log the data value on console it gave me that the message variable that comes from login.php is undefined ,I don't where is my mistake

Comment: simply return true/false from the login() function then set the message, refactor it. logined is not a word

Comment: but in login function i have three different message want to appear

Comment: then return an array `['status' => true, 'message' => 'logined successfully']` but really you want to be checking on true or false, not a string

Comment: i understood then i must merge the two message (username exist and email exist) , i wanted to have three messages

Comment: you could also throw an exception from the function and catch it, then could set any message

Comment: SM_Berwari try change the `return` by `echo` in php login function.

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using `MD5()` or `SHA1()`. 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: `localhost:3308` That might be your MySQL or mariaDB port number but it really SHOULD NOT BE your apache listening port

Comment: Thanks ,i will not use md5 it is just for test and when i upload to the server i will delete 3308 port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use "login" index in posts variable at line 4 but in jQuery ajax you don't pass any login data in request

so after finishing process in your php file there is no $message variable for echoing, and your request return is empty

use this as data in jQuery ajax (my suggestion):

```
data: { login: 1, username: username, password: password, remember: remember },
```

or use this in php file instead of "isset($_POST['login'])":

```
if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']) AND $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] == 'POST'){
```

Comment: Thanks alot ,the problem was i create the login.php inside index.php first therefore i used   "isset($_POST['login'])" ,after i moved it at separate file i forgot to delete this line ,i just deleted it and it solved